# Caching Data in next js

Tags: next.js, caching

i'm trying to implement data caching in next js 14 i have a page ( /lib/fetchData.js):
but for some reason it's always fetching the data from source instead from cache any idea on what it might be the cause ?

```
const fetchFromBackEnd = async(`/shopby/category/Snacks%20&%20Candy`) => {
  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      accept: "application/json",
    },

    next: {
      revalidate: 60 * 60 * 24,
    },
  };

  const response = await fetch(url, options);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
};
```

Comment: As far as I know, when in development mode `revalidate` acts the same as an uncached requests. Try using `yarn build && yarn start` and try it again.

Comment: it didn't work but thank you tho

Answer (score 0):

since you have this partial URL `/shopby/category/Snacks%20&%20Candy` that means you are on the client side.

[from docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#fetching-data-on-the-server-with-fetch)

> ### Fetching Data on the Server with fetch
>
> Next.js extends the native fetch Web API to allow you to configure the
> caching and revalidating behavior for each fetch request on the
> server. React extends fetch to automatically memoize fetch requests
> while rendering a React component tree.
>
> You can use fetch with async/await in Server Components, in Route
> Handlers, and in Server Actions.

Looks like `fetch` cache works on the server except route handlers

> In Route handlers, fetch requests are not memoized as Route Handlers
> are not part of the React component tree.